# I need to update a checkbox as True if there is at least 1 chatter post on a custom object (sent by sys admin profile.)

Tags: process-builder, chatter, checkbox

I need to track that my team is acknowledging support requests, by posting a chatter post to the requestor. I have a checkbox on our custom object, which I'd like a process builder to flag as True when at least 1 chatter post is present, and the sender has a System Administrator Profile.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Please take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the Help Center - especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it states, _"Questions that ask for the community to write code or provide step-by-step instructions for implementation...are likely to be closed."_ This site exists to _help_ you. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357368/edit) your question to include what you have tried and how it is not working (e.g., exact errors, issues).

Answer (score 2):

**First, a little bit context on Chatter Posts and how they relate to Custom Object**

Chatter posts on your custom object will be a `FeedItem` record, which will have `ParentId` pointing towards your Custom Object Record and the `CreatedBy` User for it would be the user with `System Administrator` Proflile.

Now since you want to set the flag as `true`, whenever a any such post exists. You will need to trigger your process builder, when ever a new feed item is added and if the inserted `FeedItem` post is being posted by `System Administrator` Profile user then check the flag on `ParentId` reference object (Custom Object) to `true`.

The conditions for Process builder would be.

1. Feed item Process builder, triggered whenever a record is being created.
2. Check if the record is being created by User.Profile.Name = `System Administrator`

I have taken case here as an example, you can add your custom object here in your process builder.

[image: Example screenshot of what the required process builder would look like]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Nice contributions - please keep contributing!

Comment: couldn't you use `$Profile.Name` of the running user rather than the `CreatedBy` relationship, seems simpler?